# Add new rows to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2` that that were computed from the same source, but with different methods, thus most of the values are same, with some differences. Now, I want to update `df1` based on values in `df2`.

For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['john','deb','john','deb'], 'col1':[490,500,425,678], 'col2':[456,625,578,789],'col3':['TN','OK','OK','NY']})
 name col1 col2 col3
 john  490  456  TN
 deb   500  625  OK
 john  425  578  OK
 deb   678  789  NY

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['deb','john','deb','john','deb'], 'col1':[400,490,500,425,678], 'col2':[225,456,625,578,789],'col3':['TN','TN','OK','OK','NY']})
 name col1 col2 col3
  deb  400  225  TN
 john  490  456  TN
  deb  500  625  OK
 john  425  578  OK
 deb   678  789  NY
```

So, in this case `.append` should append only the first row from `df2` to `df1`. So, only if there is a new row in `df2` that is not present in `df1` (based on name and `col3`) that column will be added/updated, else it wont be.

This almost seems like something that `concat` should do.

Comment: *Why* should it only append that row? How, specifically, do you decide which rows you want?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to insert a row in df2. Hope this is much clear. `col3` is a category variable, so is there is new `name` in the category, you would append.

Comment: To put it another way: you want to concatenate the two frames and then drop duplicates?   Or if there's a new row involving Deb from Oklahoma -- say `deb 1000 2000 OK` -- do you want the original `deb 500 625 OK` row to be removed?

Comment: Simply put, i just want to add a row that is unique (based on the two column). One caveat with dropping duplicate is that how do i make sure i keep the value from the df1 only?

Answer (score 21):

There are two ways of acheiving your result.

1. Concat both dataframes, then drop duplicates
2. Using an outer join/merge, then drop duplicates

I will show you both.

**Concat then Drop**

This should be more *CPU friendly*

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df3.drop_duplicates(subset=['name', 'col3'], inplace=True, keep='last')
```

This method is possibly more memory intensive than an outer join because at one point you are holding `df1`, `df2` and the result of the concatination of both `[df1, df2]` (`df3`) in memory.

**Outer join then Drop**

This should be more *memory friendly*.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=list(df1), how='outer')
df3.drop_duplicates(subset=['name', 'col3'], inplace=True, keep='last')
```

Doing an `outer` join will make sure you get all entries from both dataframes, but `df3` will be smaller than in the case where we use `concat`.

#### Version 0.15 and older note:

The keyword `keep='last'` used to be `take_last=True`